# Automorphism group of a some kind of functions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $X,Y$ are two subsets of order $n$. Consider the set of all one to one and onto functions  $f$ such that $f(X)=X$ and $f(Y)=Y$. Then it is an easy problem that automorphism group of all these functions is $S_n\times S_n$. Now, what is the automorphism group of all one to one and onto functions such that $f(X)=X, f(Y)=Y$ or $f(X)=Y, f(Y)=X$?

Comment: You are assuming $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, right? If so, how would you understand the automorphism group of just maps such that $f(X)=Y, f(Y)=X$? The answer you would like should be easy to obtain then.

Comment: Yes, they are disjoint.

Comment: A.S, Since they are disjoint. and automorphism group of all function is $S_n$, the automorphism group is $S_n\times S_n$.

Comment: -1 : The automorphism group of the direct product of two groups is not necessarily the product of the two automorphism groups. In particular we have Aut$(S_n \times S_n) = (S_n \times S_n):C_2$, the semidirect product with the cyclic 2-group $C_2$.